# How to display these input fields horizontally?

Tags: html, css, forms

i have created the standard mailchimp form, which shows the form elements vertically. I would like to have them next to each other, so that the Email text input field is next to the Submit input field, on the same line.

I cant seem to find the correct selectors unfortunately. **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zh0ktkqh/)** demo

```css
#mc_embed_signup .mce-EMAIL, #mc_embed_signup .mc-embedded-subscribe, .mc-field-group, #mce-responses, #mce-input1 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="//farmhelden.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=2e8aace70e8db891af7a653f9&amp;id=98d670e415" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">

            <div class="mc-field-group" style="width: 33%; line-height: 1.2">
                <input type="email" value="" placeholder="Email-Adresse..." name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
            </div>
            <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="b_2e8aace70e8db891af7a653f9_98d670e415" tabindex="-1" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
                <input type="submit" value="Anmelden" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" style="width: 23%; height: 20px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>


<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up your selectors for IDs and classes. ID selectors start with the `#` symbol, while class selectors start with the `.` symbol. This will do the trick:

```css
#mce-responses {
    display: none;
}

.mc-field-group, #mce-responses + div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="//farmhelden.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=2e8aace70e8db891af7a653f9&amp;id=98d670e415" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
            <div class="mc-field-group" style="width: 33%; line-height: 1.2">
                <input type="email" value="" placeholder="Email-Adresse..." name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
            </div>
            <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
            </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="b_2e8aace70e8db891af7a653f9_98d670e415" tabindex="-1" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
                <input type="submit" value="Anmelden" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" style="width: 23%; height: 20px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>


<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

(There is space between the two inputs because of your inline style of `width: 33%;`)